# How to control a set of lights with a switch and a subset with another switch

Tags: electrical

Hey i am installing recessed lights in my bedroom and was wondering if anyone had thoughts on how you would have the main switch power all of the lights but another switch only turn on a few by the closet.

Comment: If you turned the main switch off, do you need the closet switch to still work, or could the main switch "veto" the closet lights?

Comment: Would probably be less confusing to others if you just put two switches by the door (one being a 3-way) and the other 3-way by the closet.

Answer (score 1):

Wire the main light and light switch as normal.

Wire the second (closet) light and switch as normal, but instead of using the always-on circuit as a feed, use the switched feed from the main light.

This means that when the main light is on, the closet switch will turn on and off the closet light. When the main light is off, the closet switch will do nothing and the closet light will stay off.

Edit: I might have misunderstood what you're trying to do.

If you want the two sets of lights completely separate, then it's just the same as wiring two separate lights.

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this (though not inexpensively) is to use so-called "smart" switches and keypads.  I went with an Insteon system to do this in our basement remodel to do something similar.  One way to do what you want is with-

1 6-button dimmer keypad that controls the main circuit of lighting directly
1 micro-dimmer installed in the secondary circuit of lighting (the closet lights in your scenario).
1 Insteon hub.

Schematic wise- the 6-button keypad installs like a switch to the main light circuit.  The secondary light circuit (recessed cans) is hard-wired, but has the micro-dimmer installed in the junction box of the first can in the circuit.

The keypad is then set up to have its main on/off buttons turn everything off and on.  You can then turn off the secondary circuit using the "A" button on the keypad.

Total cost would be around $200 USD for the Insteon gear (~$75 for the hub, $75 for the keypad, and $50 for the micro-dimmer).

One added bonus is that your lights are now controllable remotely from your smartphone.  It is quite convenient when my wife reminds me I left the lights on downstairs ;).